# Hibernate Session/EntityManager is closed on stress test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I got a Spring Web Application with hibernate on it. I've almost finished the development and i'm running some stress test to find out what would happen if a lot a user connect on the same page at the same time.

I must have done something wrong on my Hibernate configuration or/and code because i get these errors :

```
formatedMessage : Session is closed!
Message : Session is closed!
Erreur : java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed
stacktrace : java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed
    [...]

formatedMessage : EntityManager is closed
Message : EntityManager is closed
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 55000
Ce statement a été fermé.
Erreur : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
stacktrace : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    [...]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ce statement a été fermé.
```

Here is the code :

```
public class Application
{
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "application_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "application_seq_gen", sequenceName = "application_id_seq",initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    private int id;

    private String nom;
    private Boolean autorise; //Autorise la validation automatique de l'application
    private String domaineFonctionnel;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name="applicationMail")
    @Column(name="mail")
    private Set<String> listMail;

    [...]
}

public ArrayList<Application> getListApplication() {

    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Application.class);
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

    ArrayList<Application> listApplication = new ArrayList<Application>();
    listApplication.addAll(criteria.list());

    entityManager.close();

    return listApplication;
}
```

Someone know what the problem is here ?

Comment: Maybe you run out of connection on your databse because of connection limit?

Comment: Also why are you using EntityManagerFactory ? Do you have a good reason? If not, try @PersistanceContext it should solve your problems.

Comment: I'll check on your answers and i'll come back later, thanks for comments ;)

Comment: So yes, the problem was that i run out of connection. I tried to use @PersistanceContext instead of EntityManagerFactory but all i got is a nullPointerException when i tried to access the entityManager

Comment: You can only use @PersistanceContext in classes managed by Spring. (only by spring components). Otherwise you need to stay with getting Entity managers by EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: I think Spring may not work like it should on my project. I will try looking into that first and then try to use the PersistanceContext instead of EntityManagerFactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you run out of connection on your databse because of connection limit?

If you run out of connections you should either allow more on database or check if you close all finished connections. (I see that you control your entity manager and sessions so this might be a case)

Also why are you using EntityManagerFactory ? Do you have a good reason? If not, try @PersistanceContext it should solve your problems.

You can only use @PersistanceContext in classes managed by Spring. (only by spring components). Otherwise you need to stay with getting Entity managers by EntityManagerFactory