# Session/EntityManager is closed when using PersistenceContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, load-testing, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm using EntityManager to execute queries but getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed on load testing.

```
    @PersistenceContext(name = "appEntityManager", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

public List<Map<String, Object>> runQuery(String query, Map<String, Object> args) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> result = null;
        try (Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)) {
            Query hqlQuery = session.createNativeQuery(query)
                    .setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);

            if (MapUtils.isNotEmpty(args)) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : args.entrySet()) {
                    hqlQuery.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            result = hqlQuery.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception while runQuery method {}", query, e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I tried without type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED and using Transactional on method but it's not working.
I'm using jmeter with following config:
No. of threads: 100
Ramp up time: 10s
Loop count: 1

How can I avoid this exception?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510070/4778343) will help.

Comment: If I'm running out of connections, shouldn't I get `Unable to require JDBC Connection`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you there as I haven't done anything similar.

Comment: You found the answer?